# django - static files in base template

Tags: python, html, css, django

How to make base template use static files and to make other templates that inherits base template to use same static files?

As I read in django documentation it writes about how to use static files that are used for specific app. But I can't seem to find a way to make it use static files from outside app.

Given app inherits everything, but static files.

My settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.

)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)
INSTALLED_APPS = (    
'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'south',
    'myproject.apps.finance',
    'myproject.apps.base',
    'django.contrib.admin',
  )

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
)
```

This is my current homepage settings:

url for homepage:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from myproject.views import hello

urlpatterns = patterns('',
   ('', hello),
)
```

view of homepage:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponse
import datetime

def hello(request):
    hello = "Hello World"
    return render_to_response('home/home.html', {'hello': hello})
```

homepage template:

```
{% extends "base/base.html" %}

{% block title %} My Homepage {% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<p>I say {{ hello }}</p>

{% endblock %}
```

base template:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}/css/style.css">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My Personal Finance Site</h1>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    {% block footer %}
    <section class="divider1">
    <p>Thanks for visiting my site.</p>
    <p>All rights reserved</p>
    </section>
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

my CSS file is located in empty project called base. But I think there could be better way to use static files that are outside given app.

So what would be the best way to link base template with css file to make other templates that intherits base, to get same css file configuration?

Answer (score 7):

**base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    {% block css %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}/css/style.css">
    {% endblock %}
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My Personal Finance Site</h1>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    {% block footer %}
    <section class="divider1">
    <p>Thanks for visiting my site.</p>
    <p>All rights reserved</p>
    </section>
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

**page.html**

```
{% extends "base/base.html" %}

{% block title %} My Homepage {% endblock %}

{% block css %}{{block.super}}
//put css here
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<p>I say {{ hello }}</p>

{% endblock %}
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

from project_name import settings

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
   .......
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

**settings.py**

```
import os
import sys

..........................

SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'app_name'))

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
   # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
   # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
   # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
   os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'staticfiles'),
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
   # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
   # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
   # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
   os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'templates'),
)

....................
```

Comment: It gives error with your code. It's because  block.super does not have closing tag. Also how would base.html know where to find static_url, when it does not have active app? Shouldn't there be a way to locate such static files outside apps?

Comment: Actually it was because your {{endblock}} is written incorectly. It should have been {% endblock %}. Also it does not work. It does not link with css file.

Comment: Sorry my endblock for css is wrong but I update it now. To locate files just use {{STATIC_URL}}.

Comment: So the question is. How will it know where to look for static directory? Because base template do not have its app (or in other words it is not used). I used STATIC_URL, but it does not find it. Base template is just for inheritance.

Comment: There is no problem in your base.html even though it's use as main/base you can call static files. The question is how did you call your path in your settings.py and urls.py. The problem is in that files

Comment: I never trace your code in settings yet, I just update my codes for urls on how to call static and media files so that you can access it in your templates

Comment: I've put code in urls py as you showed and got this error: "mproperlyConfigured at /
Empty static prefix not permitted". I entered path for static_root, but it did not solve the error.

Comment: OK wait I will trace your settings just don't modify my given codes

Comment: I just don't get it how django will know which and where css file is for base.html as it does not have app that links with that template.

Comment: Ok answer updated. The answer is in your settings.py by configuring the exact location of the files.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24176/discussion-between-oerp-and-cathy)

Comment: sorry I'm eating my dinner, we will talk later

Answer (score -1):

make sure that the template tag "`{% load static %}`" is at the top of your .html file. that will load your static folder.

sample

```
{% load static %}
{% extends "base/base.html" %}

{% block title %} My Homepage {% endblock %}

{% block css %}{{block.super}}
//put css here
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<p>I say {{ hello }}</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: This is not correct. It will tell you that extends "base.html" must be the first tag in the template.